# Following the attacks on Benghazi, did "thousands" of Libyan people show their support for Chris Stevens?

Tags: united-states, libya

In former Secretary of State Hillary Clinton's [testimony before the House Select Committee on Benghazi today](http://www.c-span.org/video/?328699-1/hillary-clinton-testimony-house-select-committee-benghazi-part-1), she mentioned in her opening statement that (I'm paraphrasing, but it's essentially what she said)

> After Libyans were aware of Ambassador Chris Stevens' death, thousands of people in Libya took to the streets expressing their sympathy and saying that the ambassador's murderers were neither representative of Libya nor of Islam

So, my question is, did this actually happen? Did > 1000 Libyans take to the streets protesting the ambassador's wrongful death?

The claim can be seen in the linked video around the 28th minute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few days after the ambassador's death, thousands of people (*30 000 is the number claimed by the organizers of the protest and usually found in world's media*) were in the streets for a peaceful protest against armed militia groups.

Among the protesters, some carried banners paying hommage to Chris Stevens: «Libya has lost a friend», «We want justice for Stevens».

*EDIT: a French source in* [Le Parisien libéré](http://www.leparisien.fr/international/benghazi-le-principal-groupe-salafiste-deloge-par-des-manifestants-21-09-2012-2175069.php)

> Dans la journée, des dizaines de milliers de Libyens avaient manifesté pacifiquement à Benghazi contre les milices armées, dix jours après l'attaque du consulat américain du 11 septembre 2012 qui avait coûté la vie à l'ambassadeur des Etats-Unis Chris Stevens et trois autres Américains. «Non aux groupes armés» ou «Oui à l'armée en Libye», pouvait-on lire dans la journées sur les pancartes brandies par quelque 30 000 manifestants, selon les organisateurs